# Correct pattern for BroadcastReceiver getting wakelock to start an Activity?

Tags: android

What's the right way to acquire a wakelock in a BroadcastReceiver, and hold it until an activity is started - this is what I have:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
            "tag");
        wl.acquire();  

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
            "tag");
        wl.release();  

        // I want to keep the screen on now.
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);  
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON); 
    }
}

// The broadcastreceiver is fired via AlarmManager:
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, someTime, pendingIntent);
```

Additionally, what happens if the broadcast receiver gets fired simultaneously - I assume the wakelock manager is synchronized and this won't be a problem?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using AlarmManager WAKEUP?

Comment: @VM4 no I'm not, I updated answer to show exactly what I have.

Comment: What exactly fires the broadcast you are listening for?

Comment: @VM4 oh I am doing that via AlarmManager, updated once again, see bottom of code sample.

Comment: Notifications allow a [full screen intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)) specifically for alarms and other interrupt based cases - this is what the built in Alarm and Phone apps use and probably what you should use also

Comment: @ianhanniballake awesome I did not know that, will check that out now as well.

Comment: Ok the right thing to do here is to use what @ianhanniballake suggests, I thought we had to just start our own Activity to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a lock is acquired you have to keep this instance of lock and release exactly that instance once work is done. You can check source code of [WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3.1_r1/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java) to get better idea of how this can be implemented and [used](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html).

Additionally, it's not a very good idea to start activity from a broadcast receiver. Imagine you play a game and in the middle of a level your phone starts an activity. I don't think you will like it. You should rather post a notification that user can open activity later, when user wants it.

Comment: Yeah agreed @beworker, it is for an alarm so I think it's ok to interrupt the user in this case.

Comment: I see what you're saying about WakefulBroadcastReceiver, will read through now.

Comment: You can build something similar for Activity. It's based on static list, so it could work for Activity too. The only thing you need to take care is to reliable release the wake lock. Otherwise device will discharge very fast.

Comment: Ok so I should be using a full screen intent as @ianhanniballake suggests. If you did want to really launch an activity though, then I believe this would be the way to do it.